# Response.Redirect to a UNC path

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to redirect the user to a directory on a file server using its UNC path.  I've tried using something like the following but I just get a 404 error.

```
Response.Redirect(@"file:\\fileserver\data\");
```

What's the correct syntax to make this work?

Comment: Do the people on your webapp have access to this UNC path?

Answer (score 3):

You don't quite have the file protocol identifier correct.
Try:

```
string location = String.Format("file:///{0}", @"\\fileserver\data\");
Response.Redirect(location, true);
```

Comment: I tried this but still get a page cannot be displayed error in IE7.  Could this be a browser security thing?  I tried viewing the page in FF3 and get the message "Object moved here".  I have not idea, when I simply type the UNC path into the browser it works fine, isn't that essentially what a redirect does?

Comment: That depends what error you're getting. 404 isn't a security thing, it's just a file not found. What Html Error code are you getting?

Comment: Not really sure what type of error.  IE just says "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".  I inspected the header in FF3 and it seems to be sending the correct 302 to the right location.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the `Response.Redirect` method, but you can always write the file for download by the user using `Response.WriteFile`.

This link might help: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307603/EN-US/

Code Snippet from above link:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Set the appropriate ContentType.
   Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
   //Write the file directly to the HTTP output stream.
   Response.WriteFile(@"\\server\folder\file.pdf");
   Response.End();
}
```

Comment: The question was about redirecting to a directory, rather than a file. Not sure your code snippet and example would work as is.

Answer (score 0):

file:////server/directory

Or, create a virtual directory in your Website and map it to a path, like /data/