# Using header('Location: ') to redirect to UNC path

Tags: php, redirect, header, unc

I'm working on a web site which will be viewed from several remote locations within our intranet, and also from the internet at large.  Due to bandwidth limitations to the remote locations, we are implementing a conditional rewrite for certain file types (video files, flash objects, etc.), which will be stored locally on a server within each physical location.  However, due to security requirements, we are not able to activate a web server on these remote machines, so we must be able to redirect to UNC paths using a Samba share.

We have a working solution that suits our current needs, by using mod_rewrite on the central Apache server like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(swf|mp3|wav|wmv|mov)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]+)$ unc_redirect.php?server=myserver&path=sharename&file=$2 [R,L]
```

Our php script then uses header('Location: ') to redirect to the UNC path of the requested file like so:

```
<?php
$Str_Location='file://///'.$_GET["server"].'/'.$_GET["path"].'/'.$_GET["file"];
header('Location: '.urldecode($Str_Location), 1, NULL);
?>
```

As I mentioned, this solution seems to be working well enough for our current needs.  However, it only works with Internet Explorer, and only if the site is "trusted" by IE (Firefox, Safari, and Opera all behave slightly differently but none will follow the redirect from the php script).  This is not truly an issue right now, since IE is the only browser available to the PC's that would trigger the rewrite condition, but it seems to me that there may be a better/more elegant way to achieve the same (or better) results.

I have my own theories regarding the reason for the redirect working in IE but no other browser, but I'm basically a complete newbie in this area, so I thought I might ask the experts for your take.

Comment: 'file://///' I haven't seen this protocol before. Is this a file on a network?

Comment: Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784340/response-redirect-to-a-unc-path

Comment: I saw that post prior to posting this question.  Sadly, it doesn't help me in this particular situation, as our web server is a Unix box, and currently has no support for asp.net.  If it ever really became an issue, I suppose I could install mono, but I'm not ready to do that for this issue.