# Asp.net redirect to a pdf on unc does not show up

Tags: asp.net, pdf, redirect

Right now I have these line of code to show a pdf, where the Url is a unc path to a pdf, like "file://server/folder/my.PDF"

```
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + Url);
 Response.Redirect(Url, true);
```

I want to emphasis that this code works in IE on my local but it does not work in FF or Chrome on my local.  Furthermore it does not work on our server with IE.  The symptom is that it's just loading forever and not showing the pdf.

Edit: I did see this post [Response.Redirect to a UNC path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784340/response-redirect-to-a-unc-path) and used the code on the top answer there which worked for us locally.

```
string location = String.Format("file:///{0}", @"\\fileserver\data\");   
Response.Redirect(location, true);
```

Before applying the code above which adds "file://", the pdf unc path is like this "\\server\folder\my.PDF"

Comment: Thanks Aristos, the file is on a server, if we put the file url in IE it shows up fine, just when we do the redirect it's stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I open a pdf file from a unc path:

```
 Response.ClearHeaders();
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 Response.Clear();
 Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;Filename=filename.pdf");
 Response.TransmitFile(@"\\server\folder\1.pdf");
 Response.End();
```

Comment: Thank you Katz, I marked yours as answer.  However, I had to change the last line from Response.End(); to Respond.Flush(); otherwise IIS on the server didn't like it :)